# Square coil circuit and variable magnetic field problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current, electrical-resistance, electromagnetic-induction, power

I am attempting to solve the following problem.

A square coil of side $l = 40.6 \ cm$ and resistor $R = 95.5 \ \Omega$ is contained within the $xy$ plane. Within the same region a magnetic field, variable in time, is present:

$$\vec{B} = A\cos{(\omega t)}\hat{k}$$

where $\omega = 68.5 \ s^{-1}$ and $A=5.1 \ mT$. Determine the power dissipated by the resistor $R$ at the instant $t=1.9 \ s$.

I do know the power dissipated by a resistor is $P = RI^2$. Via Faraday's law of induction, I can determine the induced electromotive force:

$$\epsilon = -\frac{d}{dt}\left(\phi(\vec{B}) \right)$$

$$\phi(\vec{B})=\int_{coil}{\vec{B} \cdot d\vec{s}} = A\cos{(\omega t)} \, l^2$$ and thus:

$$\epsilon = A \, \omega \, l^2 \, \sin{(\omega t)}$$

I'm assuming that the equation above allows me to determine what the induced electromotive force is, at any given time instant, $t$.

From Ohm's first law I can determine the induced current:

$$I = \frac{\epsilon}{R}$$

and finally determine the dissipated power, knowing:

$$P = RI^2$$

I'm sure there is a concept I have yet to grasp - does Ohm's first law apply to this specific scenario, where the electromotive force is induced into the closed circuit (I might hypothesise there could a different relationship between *induced current* and induced voltage/resistance)? If so, I would then be able to determine the power dissipated by the resistor knowing that $P = RI^2$?

Also, considering the following expression for electromotive force with respect to time (in this scenario it alternates):

$$\epsilon = A \, \omega \, l^2 \, \sin{(\omega t)}$$

Does it effectively express the *instantaneous* electromotive force at any given time (within the square coil + resistor circuit)? Thank you!